# NLTK & Stop words

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm guessing this is a straightforward question, but its alluding me.
I'm trying to grab some stop words from NLTK. I've done this a few times with no problems but I've become stuck here.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Output:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora\stopwords.zip.
True
```

Then I try:

```
stopwords.words('english')[0:10] # Show some stop words
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1e90242f42e0> in <module>()
 ----> 1 stopwords.words('english')[0:10] # Show some stop words

 NameError: name 'stopwords' is not defined
```

I understand what the message is telling me, I just don't understand why this is the case? Like I say, I've done this numerous times.

Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nltk.download` doesn't import the module. To do so, run:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

Thanks to [J. Blackadar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10210511/j-blackadar) for spotting this in an example.

Comment: Also found from an [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/removing-stop-words-nltk-python/): from nltk.corpus import stopwords

Comment: @J.Blackadar Oh, yeah; `Unzipping corpora\stopwords.zip.`

Comment: @Matthew If this answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the green tick underneath the voting buttons.